# Using an index to get an item

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list in python ('A','B','C','D','E'), how do I get which item is under a particular index number?

Example:

- Say it was given 0, it would return A.
- Given 2, it would return C.
- Given 4, it would return E.

Comment: Did you try `myList[0]` and `myList[1]`?  What happened why you tried something?  Post the code you tried, please.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you show, `('A','B','C','D','E')`, is not a `list`, it's a `tuple` (the round parentheses instead of square brackets show that).  Nevertheless, whether it to index a list **or** a tuple (for getting one item at an index), in either case you append the index in square brackets.

So:

```
thetuple = ('A','B','C','D','E')
print thetuple[0]
```

prints `A`, and so forth.

Tuples (differently from lists) are *immutable*, so you couldn't **assign** to `thetuple[0]` etc (as you could assign to an indexing of a list).  However you can definitely *just access* ("get") the item by indexing in either case.

Answer (score 16):

```
values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
values[0] # returns 'A'
values[2] # returns 'C'
# etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [_ _getitem__(key)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) function.

```
>>> iterable = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
>>> key = 4
>>> iterable.__getitem__(key)
'E'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as any other language, just pass index number of element that you want to retrieve.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
x = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(x[5])
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use [`pop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
x=[2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(x.pop(2))
```

## output is 4