# How to find the nth digit in a list in python

Tags: python

My problem this time is that I need to find the nth digit in a list previously created. Say my list was:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

How would I code my program to get a certain (th) value from the list (say the user was asked 'Which number letter would you like from 0-7?' and the user inputted '5', the program would find the 5th component in the list and print that (the program would then print 'The 5th component in the list is e))?

Comment: Have you read [the tutorial for lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)?

Comment: This is a basic operation with a list. I mean, what'd be the purpose of a list if you couldn't extract data from it? Please read the documentation first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an index to get an item, Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019909/using-an-index-to-get-an-item-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists work in an index form. So index[0] of a list is the first item. So to find the nth item in a list, your code would look something like this.

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
chosen_number = input("Which number would you like from 1-7?")
print("The item {} places into the list is {}".format(chosen_number, list[chosen_number-1]))
```

Hopefully this helps. This doesn't account for errors that might occur when the user is typing in e.g. if they type in a word.

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the value of the array which points to the value contained in index `n-1` `print(list[n-1])`

If you want to add user interface you can do:

```
import sys
p = int(sys.argv[1])
a=[...]
print(a[p-1])
```

Comment: Why do you call a list "array"? An [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is something different.

Comment: Bad habit of mine I changed it

Answer (score -1):

```
data=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
```

Arrays index start from 0 so data[0] would be 'a' and data[5] would be 'f'