# Explanation of a lambda expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lambda title: title.split(':')[0]
```

Can anyone make me understand why there is a '[0]' used after the split function. I am learning python and came across this. Any help is appreciated

Thank You

Comment: What do you get if you remove the `[0]`? Try it and it may answer your question.

Comment: `split(':')` returns a list of strings which are split around `:`. `[0]` is accessing the first index (the first split string).

Comment: @pault that was silly of me. Thanks though for the help

Comment: It's a good idea to read the python tutorial [part on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an index to get an item, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019909/using-an-index-to-get-an-item-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [0] is the get operator of a list. The function **split** will return a list that consist of text string parts separated by colon (:). The lambda when invoked will return the first part of a text before any colon.

Best of luck!