# splitting nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple thing but for some reason my mind is blocked now
what is the name of this type of data

```
[{'self': 'test', 'id': 4, 'name': 'IT Network Support'}, {'self': 'tes_1', 'id': 5, 'name': 'IT PC Support'}]
```

how to split them into 2 dictionaries

it can be also dynamic and change to

```
[{'self': 'test', 'id': 4, 'name': 'IT Network Support'}, {'self': 'tes_1', 'id': 5, 'name': 'IT PC Support'} ,{'self': 'tes_2', 'id': 6, 'name': 'IT Voice Support'} ]
```

I want a solution which can be dynamic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an index to get an item, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019909/using-an-index-to-get-an-item-python)

Comment: I'm unclear what you want the result to be. Do you want a dictionary of dictionaries? Python doesn't really allow for dynamically assigning a different number of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be:

```
dict1, dict2 = [{'self': 'test', 'id': 4, 'name': 'IT Network Support'}, {'self': 'tes_1', 'id': 5, 'name': 'IT PC Support'}]
```

Which unpacks them into the variable dict1 and dict2

You can also just index into the list directly e.g.

```
dict_list = [{'self': 'test', 'id': 4, 'name': 'IT Network Support'}, {'self': 'tes_1', 'id': 5, 'name': 'IT PC Support'}]
dict1 = dict_list[0]
dict2 = dict_list[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack iterables in python!

`a, b = [{'self': 'test', 'id': 4, 'name': 'IT Network Support'}, {'self': 'tes_1', 'id': 5, 'name': 'IT PC Support'}]`

Comment: what if the 2 dictionaries became 3 , how to make it dynamic ?

Comment: in python3 you can unpack like `a, *b = [1, 2, 3]` where everything else goes into `b`, but otherwise I would say use a for loop and perform whatever operation you need to on it in a throwaway variable `for d in dict_list:`