# How can I print the second element in this list?

Tags: python

```
friends = ["John", "Mark", "James"]
for friend in friends:
    print(friend)
```

How can I print the second element in this list using the for loop?
I know how to get the second element in a list but I don't know how to get it using a `for` loop.

Comment: print(friends[1])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using an index to get an item, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019909/using-an-index-to-get-an-item-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just do:

```
print(friends[1])
```

That would give the second element, it will output:

```
Mark
```

If you want to use a loop, try:

```
for i, v in enumerate(friends):
    if i == 1:
        print(v)
```

Output:

```
Mark
```

Python indexing starts from 0, so the second element's index would be 1.

The for loop I did iterates through the list, but the iterator `i` is the index of every element, and `v` is the value, so it check if `i` (the index) is `1`, if so, it prints `v`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a counter for such problems. I've set it to `0` and for every iteration, it gets incremented by `1`. So, to access the  2nd element `cnt` would be `2`. You can add an `if` statement and print only `Mark`

```
friends = ["John", "Mark", "James"]
cnt=0
for friend in friends:
    cnt+=1
    if cnt==2:
         print(friend)
```