# summing a column in python

Tags: python, sum

I have a list of lists which consists of numerical data, a kind of matrix.
I'd like to create a function to sum up any column I later choose (1+2+9+10=?, 3+4+11+12=?, etc.)
The restraints are that I want to accomplish that by using for loops, and old-school python, no numpy, preferably without the zip function.
outside the loop I'd like to calculate an average within every column.
What would be the simplest way to accomplish that ?
Here's what I came up with thus far:

```
data = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8], [9, 11, 13, 15], [10, 12, 14, 16]]

def calc_avg(data, column):
    total = 0
    for row in data:
        total +=  ....
    avg = total / len(calc_avg)
```

later on, I would print the average for the column I choose.

Comment: `total += row[column]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using an index to get an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019909/using-an-index-to-get-an-item)

Comment: total += row[column], seems to work. How would the avg be defined then?

Comment: `total / len(data)` ??

Comment: Yeah, got it. Don't know how I got this mixed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a variable `nr` to keep count of number of rows added as you loop.

```
def calc_avg(data, column):
    total = 0
    nr = 0
    for row in data:
        nr += 1
        total +=  row[column]
    return total / nr
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need some counter to keep track of the "denominator" for your average -

```
data = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8], [9, 11, 13, 15], [10, 12, 14, 16]]

def calc_avg(data, column):
    total = 0
    counter = 0
    for row in data:
        total +=  row[column]
        counter += 1
    avg = total / counter
    return avg
```

Comment: Or just use `len(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple function to collect all column values and perform a math op.
Eg.

```
def get_sum_avg(chosen_column, dataset):
    # filter the column values. Ignore rows with no such col
    chosen_column_values = [element[chosen_column - 1] for element in dataset if len(element) >= chosen_column]
    # find sum
    col_sum = sum(chosen_column_values)

    # find avg
    average = col_sum / len(chosen_column_values) if len(chosen_column_values) > 0 else 0

    return col_sum, average


data = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8], [9, 11, 13, 15], [10, 12, 14, 16]]
print(get_sum_avg(1, data))
```